# PowerBI api returns a dataflow that later return a 400 status of bad request ("code": "InvalidRequest")

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-api

I'm getting refering to the `dataflows` api with

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/dataflows/](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/dataflows/)

The api response returns a list with dataflows, then I'm getting a specific dataflow with

[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/dataflows/{dataflowId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/dataflows/%7BdataflowId%7D)

While making sure the {dataflowId} was taken from the dataflows response, but I'm getting an error of 400 (Bad request):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Unexpected dataflow error: "
    }
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting the `InvalidRequest` (I'm sure the `dataflowId` was taken from the response)?

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/troubleshoot-rest-api) are not so helpfull with that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its a ghost-like-dataflow who was deleted, deleted via the global admin account.

Otherwise it will still come within the dataflows api.